# Don't change logo height in bootstrap navbar

Tags: navbar, mobirise

I've a website: http://renaatdelporte.be/RESURGE_test/
I want the navbar logo to have he same size when you scroll.
I don't want the logo to have another size than the one you see when you arrive on the website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your navbar class :

data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197"

you can read more about affix here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).